# How to find data column in map graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm attempting to produce a map graph, see code below. For some reason I keep getting the error object not found. I'm not sure why some of the variables cannot be found even though I see them in the dataset view. Data can be downloaded [here](https://file.io/ZDE8FclwKcK7). Any thoughts on why the data columns are not being picked up on?

```
#Import Libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

# Import data

Misquito_Species <- read_excel("Desktop/Misquito Species.xls")
View(Misquito_Species)
MS$State <- tolower(Species$State)
colnames(MS)[2] <- "Misquito_Species"

# Get state map data
map_data <- map_data("state")

# Manipulate data
map_data <- left_join(map_data, MS, by = c("region" = "State"))
map_data1 <- map_data %>% filter(!is.na(Misquito_Species))

# Used as label coordinate for country's names
region.lab.data <- map_data1 %>%
group_by(region) %>%
summarise(long = mean(long), lat = mean(lat),                n     

Misquito_Species=mean(Misquito_Species) )


 # import State Abbreviation
 State_Abbreviation <- read.csv("H:/Upwork/Dia Adams/State Abbreviation.csv",  
 header      

 = TRUE)
 Abbreviation <- left_join(region.lab.data,State_Abbreviation,by = c("region" =   
 "State"))



 # Plot the US map with lollipop data points
 Map6 <- ggplot() +
 geom_polygon(data = map_data, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), color =        

 'gray', fill = NA, alpha = 0.35) +
 coord_map() +
 theme_void() +
 geom_point(data = region.lab.data, aes(x = long, y = lat, size = Misquito_Species,     
 fill = Misquito_Species), 
         shape = 21, color = "black") +
 scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") +
 scale_size(range = c(5, 14)) +  
 geom_text(data = Abbreviation, aes(x = long, y = lat, label =      
 paste(Misquito_Species,Abbreviation)),
        color = "black", size = 3, nudge_y = -0.8) +  # Add text labels
 labs(size = "No of Misquito Species", title = "Number of Misquito Species by State   

 - US") +
 theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold",hjust = 0.5, margin =         

 margin(b = 20)))

 Map6

 # Plot the US map without lollipop data points
 Map6.1 <- ggplot() +
 geom_polygon(data = map_data, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), color =     

 'gray', fill = NA, alpha = 0.35) +
  coord_map() +
  theme_void() +
  geom_point(data = region.lab.data, aes(x = long, y = lat, size =   

  Misquito_Species,     
  fill = Misquito_Species), 
         shape = 21, color = "black") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "red", high = "green") +
  scale_size(range = c(5, 14)) +
  labs(size = "No of Misquito Species", title = "Number of Misquito Species by   
  State   

  - US") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 16, face = "bold",hjust = 0.5, margin =     

  margin(b = 20)))

  Map6.1
```

Comment: You load you data into `Misquito_Species`, after `View()` you attempt to use `MS` and `Species` instead, i.e. `MS$State <- tolower(Species$State)` should read 
`Misquito_Species$State <- tolower(Misquito_Species$State)`. Flagged this as a typo for now. BTW, your shared file was for a single download only and is now deleted.